# Add Service Reference Error in finding entity/Default/18.200.001?wsdl for Acumatica course I300 example

Tags: wsdl, acumatica

Acumatica course I300 has an example of building MyBIIntegration application. One of the first steps is to add a Service Reference from an address http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/18.200.001?wsdl

When I click go, I get an error:

"There was an error downloading ' http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/18.200.001?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/18.200.001?wsdl'."

Where to get that WSDL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who looked into.

I found the answer on the screen SM207060: it shows Endpoint Service WSDL as 
http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001?wsdl&company=MyTenant

One MUST include the company name: &company=MyTenant into the link.

http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001?wsdl&company=MyTenant, 
while the manual shows it as

http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001?wsdl